# Python Crash Course RandomWalk Issue AttributeError: 'RandomWalk' object has no attribute 'x_values'

Tags: python

I have followed the same code as in book, but however getting errors

```
from random import choice

class RandomWalk():

def __int__(self, num_points=5000):
    self.num_points = num_points

    self.x_values = [0]
    self.y_values = [0]

def get_step(self):
    direction = choice([1, -1])
    distance = choice(list(range(0, 8)))
    step = direction * distance
    return step

def fill_walk(self):

    while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:

        x_step = self.get_step()
        y_step = self.get_step()

        if x_step == 0 and y_step == 0:
            continue

        next_x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
        next_y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step

        self.x_values.append(next_x)
        self.y_values.append(next_y)
```

**visual.py**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random_walk import RandomWalk

rw = RandomWalk()
rw.fill_walk()
plt.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, s=15)
plt.show()
```

'''
**Error:**

C:\My_Data\Rapid.venv\py3.9.0\Scripts\python.exe "C:/My_Data/Rapid/Experiences/Coding/Python/Hands-On/06.Python Crash Course/08.visual.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\My_Data\Rapid\Experiences\Coding\Python\Hands-On\06.Python Crash Course\08.visual.py", line 5, in 
rw.fill_walk()
File "C:\My_Data\Rapid\Experiences\Coding\Python\Hands-On\06.Python Crash Course\random_walk.py", line 19, in fill_walk
while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:
AttributeError: 'RandomWalk' object has no attribute 'x_values'

Process finished with exit code 1

'''

Comment: Seems to be a typo. Replace `__int__` with `__init__`. Object attribtues are set in the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a typo. Replace `__int__` with `__init__`. Object attributes are set in the `__init__` method.

Comment: thanks a lot. Very simple mistake, I was unable to find.